# ListView horizontal = {true} breaks application with app registry error

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native, react-native-ios

The error I get is: **"Application PRSNT_prototype has not been registered"**

The folder name of my project is PRSNT_demo and these are the codes that I think might be the issue:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('PRSNT_demo', () => Main);

<ListView
              horizontal={true}
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow={(rowData) => <View>{rowData}</View>}
            />
```

When ever i turn horizontal={true} on the app breaks. **Ive tried turning the app on and off again, also tried:**

```
<ListView
                  style={Style.horList}
                  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                  renderRow={(rowData) => <View>{rowData}</View>}
                />
```

With style.horlist being:

```
horList: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
```

},

This álso broke the app.

If someone could help me out that would be absolutely amazing, thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making the ListView a ScrollView, this worked fine:

```
<ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} horizontal={true}>

    <Text>Item 1</Text>
    <Text>Item 2</Text>
    <Text>Item 3</Text>
    <Text>Item 4</Text>

</ScrollView>
```